# Flag feedback where moderator response is disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, feedback

I flagged this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889809/total-least-square-method-using-r) as being from a user that had generated several user accounts to post related Q on the TLS methodology. In my flag I linked to the other user I suspected was the same person:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/871114/dail

and also linked to a duplicate Q from the suspected same user:

[How to calculate Total least squares in R? (Orthogonal regression)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6872928/429846)

My flag was marked Invalid. Since then, the user has changed their Name to "Dail" (it was something else when I flagged but clearly from the same user if one had followed these postings about TLS on CrossValidated and SO) but now has two accounts (i) in addition to the one above, (ii) this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/869339/dail

Is there a better place than Meta to raise these issues with flagging and Mod responses? If I had thinner skin I might be discouraged from flagging content if the response from a Mod was an Invalid that was, at the very least, suspect.

How do I find out what the problem was with the flag? Do I re-flag to get these accounts merged, possibly risking further Invalids?

Comment: Er - you've linked to the same account. I think you meant this one http://stackoverflow.com/users/871114/dail

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for that - copy/paste issue. My flag was correct linked.

Comment: I've also flagged one of the posts as well. The user is unregistered so it's all too easy for them to generate multiple accounts.

Comment: Unregistered accounts can be merged by the person himself asking.. you can advice the user in a comment to Register and have "permanent" account.

Comment: @Shadow that particular user has been particularly stubborn in responding to our attempts to help, clarify and otherwise prompt.

Comment: Yeah, we got those as well sometimes.. in such case keep doing what you do so far to have all the accounts merged or destroyed - and like Jeff said, reflagging is valid option sometimes.

Comment: Looks like the two accounts have been merged. No Fair! I didn't get a chance to re-flag and recoup a small % of the flag weight I lost! ;-) (Seriously though) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realize that the mods handle sometimes upwards of **six hundred flags *per day*** and some mistakes are inevitable.

So I would certainly not take it personally, all flags are appreciated, but there are a LOT of them and we are only human. (Well except for Bill the Lizard who is a *friggin' machine*.)

Therefore, I would try flagging again and maybe be more explicit or clear in your flag; relevant URLs are always helpful and context to explain what is going on so we can handle it quickly.

Comment: Really? I always figured that Bill was, y'know, a reptile.

Comment: I do realise, and appreciate, the volume of flags that get handled, and we are all human (Bill, perhaps, aside). The lack of two-way on flags does mean it is difficult to determine why a flag was rejected. I don't want to add to the volume of flags if I've overlooked something and my flag is really Invalid, for example.

Comment: @GraceNote: He's sort of both. I think [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UU9CF.jpg) is a fair approximation of Bill at work.